# jquery droppable accepting more than 1 element / selectors

Tags: jquery, user-interface, droppable

cont from here: [jquery droppable accept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444469/jquery-droppable-accept)

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: function(d) { 
        if(d.hasClass("foo")||(d.attr("id")=="bar")){ 
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

what if i wasn't targeting an element but a set of elements? like "ul#moo li" for example. how would i change the IF condition???

Answer (score 0):

apparently this works

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: ('ul#moo_A li', 'ul#moo_B li'),
    }
});
```