# jquery drag and drop revert options

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

In html I have a list of 10 draggable `div`s called *piles* and another list of 10 droppable `div`s called *stacks*. Each *pile* will have unique id that will match with one of the *stack* divs.

- If the *pile* **does not** match with the *stack* the draggable div should revert to its default position.
- If the pile **does** match with the *stack* the draggable div will be placed inside that stack.

> ```
> After the pile has matched the stack when i drag out the matched
> *pile* from that stack it should automatically reposition to the exact list of *piles**
> ```

Comment: the pile does match with the stack the draggable div will be placed inside that stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about it on these SO questions dealing with `conditional revert` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4302882/1366033), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3088485/1366033), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1444469/1366033)), but this is different enough to warrant it's own question.

Basically you want to set the [`revert option`](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert) to `'invalid'` on your [`.draggable()`](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) object, and it'll go back if it wasn't successfully dropped onto a droppable, like this:

```js
$(".draggable").draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
```

Then in your [`.droppable()`](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) you can set what's considered valid for a drop using the [`accept option`](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept).  Accept can be implemented as a function that returns `true` or `false` based on whether or not it will accept elements. Our droppable declaration will look like this:

```js
$(".droppable").droppable({ 
    accept: function(drag) {
        var dropId = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var dragId = $(drag).attr('data-id');
        return dropId === dragId;
    }
});
```

In this example, i'm using data attributes to match drag and drop elements, but you can do it however you like.  Here's some sample **HTML**:

```
<div class="draggable" data-id='a'>draggable a</div>
<div class="droppable" data-id='a'>droppable a</div>
```

Here's a serious demo:

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Wdyd6/)

Here's a playful demo:

## [Fun Fruit Mix and Match Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/Wdyd6/3/)